# Tomcat: log4j doesn't rotate log-file

Tags: tomcat, log4j, logrotate

Have an odd problem with log-file rotating.

We use `log4j`.

In `[...]/apache-tomcat-5.5.23/conf/log4j.xml file have:`

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
<param name="maxFileSize" value="100MB" />
<param name="maxBackupIndex" value="20" />
```

Tomcat runnig with this file:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=/home/***/apache-tomcat-5.5.23/conf/log4j.xml
```

But file for now 1.1G. About week ago it's worked correct.

First idea was that sombody locked it - but then I test this very Tomcat on other server where nobody else can be logged in - and have 186M filesize...

What cause of this problem can be else? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you configuration file is used ? You shoud be able to verify it by turning on the log4j.debug `-Dlog4j.debug`.

Answer (score 2):

Found problem...

Java-devs make an typo while updating `log4j.xml`:

What we have:

`<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">`

But must be:

`<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">`